# Ecto association to more than one schemes

Tags: associations, elixir, ecto

Let's say I have these schemas:

```
defmodule Sample.Post do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "post" do
    field :title
    has_many :comments, Sample.Comment
  end
end

defmodule Sample.User do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "user" do
    field :name
    has_many :comments, Sample.Comment
  end
end

defmodule Sample.Comment do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "comment" do
    field :text
    belongs_to :post, Sample.Post
    belongs_to :user, Sample.User
  end
end
```

My questions is how can I use `Ecto.build_assoc` to save a comment?

```
iex> post = Repo.get(Post, 13)
%Post{id: 13, title: "Foo"}
iex> comment = Ecto.build_assoc(post, :comments)
%Comment{id: nil, post_id: 13, user_id: nil}
```

So far it's ok, all I need to do is use the same function to set the `user_id` in my `Comment` struct, however since the return value of `build_assoc` is `Comment` struct,  I can not use the same function

```
iex> user = Repo.get(User, 1)
%User{id: 1, name: "Bar"}
iex> Ecto.build_assoc(user, :comment, comment)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Sample.Comment.delete/2
...
```

I have two options but neither of them looks good to me:

First one is to set `user_id` manually!

```
iex> comment = %{comment| user_id: user.id}
%Comment{id: nil, post_id: 13, user_id: 1}
```

Second one is to convert the struct to map and ... I don't even want to go there

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you want convert struct to map? It is really easy.

`build_assoc` expects map of attributes as last value. Internally it tries to delete key `:__meta__`. Structs have compile time guarantees, that they will contain all defined fields, so you are getting:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Sample.Comment.delete/2
```

But you can just write:

```
comment = Ecto.build_assoc(user, :comment, Map.from_struct comment)
```

and everything will work fine.

Comment: I thought I need to remove `__meta__` before sending it to  `build_assoc `!

Answer (score 4):

Just pass it along with `build_assoc`

```
iex> comment = Ecto.build_assoc(post, :comments, user_id: 1)
%Comment{id: nil, post_id: 13, user_id: 1}
```

Check [here](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html#build_assoc/3) for more details.